Trying to name a feature
I am working in QGIS 3.36.2 on a simple map, with some polygons that were imported from Google Earth.
There is one polygon on the layer.  This polygon is currently named "untitled polygon" in the field called 'Name'.
I would like to label the polygon on the map, but when I add a label using the 'name' field, the polygon is labelled as 'Untitled Polygon' on the map.
I have tried everything I can think of and I cannot find out how to change the content of the 'name' field from 'Untitled Polygon' to something more useful.
I have toggled editing in the layer, but when I go to the attribute table I can't seem to change the value of the 'name' field.  I cannot directly edit the field, nor can I set up a function to update the value ("name" = 'NewPolyName').
I have ensured I have write access to all of the datafiles and directory, and everything else I can think of...maybe I'm coming at it wrong, I don't know but I've wasted hours on what seems like an absurdly simple task.

Are the polygons from Google Earth in a KML/KMZ file?

convert to shapefile/geopackage then edit your file.

This was the solution.  It's not clear in the documentation that QGIS can't edit an imported kms/kml...I wound up treating it like a base layer and creating new layers on top with new content.  Thanks for the help.
